# Alert Dialogue null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullreferenceexception

I have an alertDialogue popup when a user wants to create a game, and it asks the user how many points they would like to gamble in the game, but it keeps throwing a null reference error and I am not too sure why.

This is my alertDialogue positive button click listener

```
 alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Confirm Wager", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            createLobbyGame();
                            double wagerD;
                            String wager;
                            TextView wagerRV = findViewById(R.id.wagerRV);

                            wagerD = Double.parseDouble(edittext.getText().toString());
                            wager = Double.toString(wagerD);
                            boolean wage = wager.endsWith("0");

                            if(wage) {
                                wagerRV.setText(wager+"0");
                            } else {
                                wagerRV.setText(wager);
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

It throws an error when it tries to setText. This is the error it throws

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

I know I had this working in the past, but I must have changed something to make it not work properly anymore but I have no idea what I would have changed.

I know this is a very common and simple problem, but I have looked at many other answers and have not found a solution that works for me.

Any help?

---

TextView declaration:

```
TextView wagerRV = (TextView) ((AlertDialog.Builder) alertDialog).findViewById(R.id.wagerRV);
```

How I am defining alertDialog:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(FlipCoinLobby.this);
final EditText edittext = new EditText(FlipCoinLobby.this);

alertDialog.setView(edittext);
```

Comment: As far as I remember, you need to change `findViewById(R.id.wagerRV)` to `alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.wagerRV)`. You might need to cast it as well.

Comment: @brentB You probably call `findViewById(R.id.wagerRV)` on a wrong activity: it can't find the `TextView`. Could you post your activity code and layout XML?

Answer (score 1):

Your `wagerRV` is null because it can't find `R.id.wagerRV`.

You need to retrieve views from within `onClick()` using the dialog reference.

Change

```
TextView wagerRV = findViewById(R.id.wagerRV);
```

to

```
TextView wagerRV = (TextView) ((AlertDialog) alertDialog).findViewById(R.id.wagerRV);
```

Remove any unnecessary casting (I don't have IDE at the moment).

**Update** based on comments and question edit:-

`alertDialog.setView(edittext)` --> your `alertDialog` does not have any TextView with id `R.id.wagerRV`. Please check out some examples online on setting the content view with XML and that XML should have that TextView. If your `wagerRV` is in the activity and not inside the dialog, then declare it at the activity level, not inside `onClick` of alertDialog.

**Update 2**

You need to change your builder to the actual AlertDialog using `AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();`. And then the casting will work too.

Comment: If I use alertDialog before the findViewById it is unable to resolve findViewById. Is there something I am doing wrong? I believe I have the casting correct. I changed AlertDialog to AlertDialog.Builder because that is what I am using.

Comment: @brentB can you show your exact code of this line and also the way you declared `alertDialog`? AlertDialog extends Dialog, which does have the [findViewById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog#findViewById(int)) method

Comment: Just added it to the bottom of the post

Comment: @brentB added another update, looks like there are many issues with this, I suggest going through a alert dialog tutorial online

Comment: Thanks for all the details. I will rework my alertDialog just so it works a bit better, but I solved my issue. The wagerRV was being drawn on the screen after the setText was being called, so I had to swap that around so that after the TextView was drawn it could be set. Thanks for the help.